# Difference between a+b and a.__add__(b)

Tags: python

I am currently trying to understand where the difference between using `a+b` and `a.__add__(b)` is when it comes to custom classes. There are numerous websites that say that using the '+'-operator results in using the special method `__add__` - which is fine so far.

But when i run the following example I get two different results.

```
class C:  
  def __add__(self, other):
    print("C.__add__", self, other)
    return "result"  
  def __radd__(self, other):
    print("C.__radd__", self, other)    
    return "reversed result"

c = C()
print(1+c)
print()
print(1 .__add__(c))
print(int.__add__(1,c))
```

Result:

```
C.__radd__ <C object at 0x7f60b92e9550> 1
reversed result

NotImplemented
NotImplemented
```

Now from what I understood, when executing `1+c` Python checks/executes the int `__add__` method - finds that there is no implementation for adding int and C objects - returns NotImplemented - which lets Python know to check object C for `__radd__` and executes the code within.

Why does `1+c` result in executing the `__radd__` code but the other two version are just returning `NotImplemented` without checking `__radd__` ??

Comment: Er, because you called `__add__` directly? As you state, Python only does the fallback when you use the `+` operator.

Comment: Guess I wasn't aware that the fallback will not be used if I used `__add__` directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a+b` is equivalent to `import operator; operator.add(a,b)`. It starts by calling `a.__add__(b)` and then, if necessary, `b.__radd__(a)`. But `ifsubclass(type(b), type(a))`, then `b.__radd__(a)` is called first.

Based on the [docs on "special" methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names):

- Regarding [`__add__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__):

  > `__add__()` is called to implement the binary arithmetic "+" operation. For instance, to evaluate the expression x + y, where x is an instance of a class that has an `__add__()` method, `x.__add__(y)` is called.
  >
  > If one of those methods does not support the operation with the supplied arguments, it should return **NotImplemented**.
- Regarding [`__radd__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__):

  > These functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types. For instance, to evaluate the expression x + y, where y is an instance of a class that has an `__radd__()` method, `y.__radd__(x)` is called if `x.__add__(y)` returns NotImplemented.
  >
  > If the right operand’s type is a subclass of the left operand’s type and that subclass provides the reflected method for the operation, this method will be called before the left operand’s non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to override their ancestors’ operations.

**Explanation with the examples based on the behaviour:**

**Case 1:**

```
>>> print 1+c
('C.__radd__', <__main__.C instance at 0x7ff5631397a0>, 1)
reversed result
```

These functions `radd` are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types. In this case, `1` does not support addition of the class hence, it falls back to the `__radd__()` function of the `C` class. In case `__radd__` was not implement in `C()` class, it would have fallen back to `__add__()`

**Case2:**

```
>>> 1 .__add__(c)
NotImplemented
>>> c .__add__(1)
('C.__add__', <__main__.C instance at 0x7ff563139830>, 1)
'result'
```

`1 .__add__(c)` gives `NotImplemented` as `1` is of `int` type and `add` of `int` class do not supports `add` with C class object. But `c .__add(1)` run because `C()` class supports that.

**Case 3:**

```
>>> int.__add__(1, c)
NotImplemented
>>> C.__add__(c, 1)
('C.__add__', <__main__.C instance at 0x7ff5610add40>, 1)
'result'
```

Similar to `case 2`. But here, the call is made via class with first argument as object of that class. Behaviour would be same.

**Case 4:**

```
>>> int.__add__(c, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor '__add__' requires a 'int' object but received a 'instance'
>>> C.__add__(1, c)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method __add__() must be called with C instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

Vice-versa of `case 3`. As is cleared from the stack-trace, `__add__` expected the object of the calling class as the first argument, failing which resulted in exception.

Comment: So basically there happens more behind the scene when using the `+` operator which is responsible for the fallback?

Comment: Updated an answer. I tried my best to explain regarding how it works. In case of doubt, let me know. I'll further make an edit and will try to be more clear

Comment: Maybe I should paraphrase my question - what is the difference between using the `+` operator and the __add__ function?
Reading about special methodes it looks like there is none - but apparently the `NotImplemented` case is handled differently

Comment: Yes. There is no difference. `1+2` is equivalent to `1 .__add__(2)`

Comment: So why does `1+c` run like this: `__add__ of int --> __radd__ of C` but `1 .__add__.(c)` runs like `__add__ of int --> NotImplemented`

Comment: As I mentioned above in the answer **`__radd__` functions are only called if the left operand does not support the corresponding operation and the operands are of different types** <-- which is the case

Comment: It finally sunk in :D Thank you!

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri `a+b` is NOT equivalent to a.__add__(b).  `a+b` IS equivalent to `import operator; operator.add(a,b)`.  The `add` function is the 'more behind the scene'.  It usually starts by calling `a.__add__(b) and then, if necessary, `b.__radd__(a).  But `ifsubclass(type(b), type(a))`, then `b.__radd__(a)` is (should be) called first.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: Yes, and I mentioned the same in my answer (check description of __radd__()). In which part you are having doubt regarding that? May be I should correct that.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: I responded to your comment, 5th above mine.  " There is no difference. 1+2 is equivalent to 1 .__add__(2)"  Perhaps you meant that specifically because `1` and `2` are both ints where as I took it too generally.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: Yes, my comment was specifically for `1` and `2` and it is good that you pointed it out. May be someone seeing it in the future would have the felt the same. I should have mentioned that in my comment.