# Why does str + Markup return a Markup object?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

With [MarkupSafe](https://markupsafe.palletsprojects.com), which is used in Jinja and Flask, adding a `str` object and a `Markup` object returns a `Markup` object:

```
>>> from flask import Markup
>>> 'foo' + Markup('bar')
Markup('foobar')
```

But if I call `str.__add__` directly, it returns a `str` object:

```
>>> 'foo'.__add__(Markup('bar'))
'foobar'
```

So it seems that adding `str` and `Markup` with `+` calls `Markup.__add__` regardless of the order of the operands. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operator calls `Markup.__radd__` instead of `str.__add__` because the right operand's type (`Markup`) is a subclass of the left operand's type (`str`).

(see [Difference between a+b and a.__add__(b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625229/difference-between-ab-and-a-add-b))

When calling `str.__add__` on a `Markup` object, the `Markup` object is just seen as a `str` object and the operation is done considering `str` type only.

Comment: I don't think `str.__add__` delegates to `Markup.__radd__` because `Markup` is a subclass of `str`. I think `str.__add__` just returns `NotImplemented` if it can't handle the argument's type.

Comment: no (that's what I thought first too), since Markup IS a string (see the `isinstance` test in my answer). Else str.__add__ would fail when called a `Markup` object too.

Comment: But I can define a class `A` that is NOT a subclass of `str`, and `'foo' + A()` calls `A.__radd__`.

Comment: So it's not dependent on the second operand being a subclass of `str`.

Comment: Ah, I see. My only issue with your answer is the wording of "`str.__add__` delegates to `Markup.__radd__`". If I understand correctly, `str.__add__` is not called at all, it is the `+` operator that delegates to `Markup.__radd__` because the right operand is a subclass of the left operand. I will accept this answer if you change the wording to something like "the `+` operator delegates to `Markup.__radd__`".

Comment: I would also delete the extraneous information. The `int` and `isinstance` examples seem unnecessary to me. You really only need one sentence like, "The `+` operator calls `Markup.__radd__` instead of `str.__add__` because the right operand's type (`Markup`) is a subclass of the left operand's type (`str`)." Plus the source linked at the bottom of the answer. And maybe one more sentence like, "Note that this is not the only case in which an object's `__radd__` method may be called." Then the reader can search for more information on `__radd__` if they like.

Comment: @jth Yes. [The documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) says *If the right operand’s type is a subclass of the left operand’s type and that subclass provides the reflected method for the operation, this method will be called before the left operand’s non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to override their ancestors’ operations.*